# Qt 5.11.0 with CMake on Windows, Qt bundled MinGW

Tags: c++, qt, cmake

I'm trying to build Qt project on Windows. Project build system is CMake.
CMake contains Qt initialization:

```
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
find_package( Qt5Core REQUIRED )
find_package( Qt5Widgets REQUIRED )
find_package( Qt5Gui REQUIRED )
qt5_add_resources(RESOURCE_ADDED ${QT_RESOURCES})

qt5_wrap_cpp(UI_SOURCE
    ${QOBJECT_HEADERS}
)

qt5_wrap_ui(
    UI_HDRS
    ${UI_FILES}
)
```

Also, CMakeLists file has linkage data

```
target_link_libraries(SampleProject
        Qt5::Core
        Qt5::Widgets
        Qt5::Gui
)
```

But when I building project I receive linkage errors that looks like:

```
undefined reference to `__imp__ZN16QCoreApplication19setOrganizationNameERK7QString`
```

Building with key: `-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=path_to_qt\Qt\5.11.0\mingw53_32`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using   `QCoreApplication::setOrganizationName()` in your project? how?

Comment: @MohammadKanan Ye, I'm using it like this: `QCoreApplication::setOrganizationName("ORGNAME");`. But I'm getting this errors for all methods and functions I'm using.

Comment: Can you should the *full* CMakeLists.txt ? how is the "SampleProject" target defined?

Comment: Your question is not containing enough data for it to be answered. Please add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For example this issue might be caused by the missing `target_link_libraries`.